# ROS2 robot_localization not working correctly with namespace

Tags: localization, ros2

I have a straightforward ROS2 launch script that launches the following:

- gazebo client, gazebo server and spawn_entity to spawn a robot in gazebo
- robot_state_publisher and map->odom static publisher
- robot_localization
- Nav2

Everything starts up correctly. However, when set a namespace to be used for all the entities in the launch file, `robot_localization` stops functioning correctly. Specifically, it does not subscribe to the topics `/namespace/odom` or `/namespace/imu` (The robot published both these messages correctly).

Any idea why?

Here are parts of the launch script for reference

```
remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'), 
              ('/tf_static', 'tf_static')]

robot_localization_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package = 'robot_localization',
    executable = 'ekf_node',
    name = 'ekf_filter_node',
    output = 'screen',
    parameters = [os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config', 'ekf.yaml'), 
                  {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
    remappings = remappings,
    namespace = namespace
)

#note: if 'use_composition' is True, the nav2 stack will not start if a namespace is given
nav2_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(nav2_launch_dir, 'bringup_launch.py')),
    launch_arguments = {'map': static_map_path, 
                        'params_file': nav2_params_path, 
                        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 
                        'autostart': autostart_nav2,
                        'namespace': namespace,
                        'use_namespace': 'True',
                        'use_composition': 'False'}.items()
)
```

And below are the `robot_localization` configurations used for the transforms and the sensors

```
frequency: 30.0
publish_tf: true
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: odom

odom0: odom
odom0_config: [true,  true,  true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]

imu0: imu
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, false]
```

Comment: What happens when you `ros2 node info ekf_filter_node`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the subscriptions in RL node config. The lines that state, "odom0: odom" should include the namespace, like namespace/odom

Comment: That didn't solve the problem